# Robot Framework Log Keyword - Parameter 'console' not working

Tags: logging, console, robotframework

In Robot you can use the `Log` keyword with parameter `console`. The documentation says this:

> If the `console` argument is true, the message will be written to
> the console where test execution was started from in addition to the
> log file.

I tried it this way:

```
Log  message=blabla  level=TRACE  console=${True}
```

Unfortunatyl it behaves the same like

```
Log  message=blabla  level=TRACE    # console=${False} > is default
```

That means in both cases I don't have an output at the console.
Whats wrong or what did I wrong?

Comment: Your first example works fine for me. Are you aware that the message you're writing won't necessarily appear on a separate line? Maybe it's there but you're looking in the wrong place for it.

Comment: oh no .. you are right. What a simple reason, thanks.

Comment: You can add a newline to force it to appear on a new line: `log   message=\nblahblah`.

Comment: If this is no longer a problem, I recommend that you close this question.